# PHP Array Unique on exploded Keywords from MySQL problem

Tags: php, database, array

I'm trying to echo keywords from a MySQL database, separated by colon, and remove (don't show) duplicates.

This is what I got.

**Keywords in DB**

```
Love:Sorrow:Death
Happiness:Love:Excitement
Excitement:Speed:Love
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$myKeyArr = array();
while($rowKeyword = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlKeyword)){
  $myKeywords = explode(':', $rowKeyword['keywords']);
  $myKeyArr[] = $myKeywords;
}

foreach ($myKeyArr as $value) {
  $kw = array_unique($value);
  echo $kw['0'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

**I just want to echo the following**

```
Love
Sorrow
Death
Happiness
Excitement
Speed
```

**This is what's shown**

```
Love
Sorrow
Death
Happiness
Love
Excitement
Excitement
Speed
Love
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code by following code.

```
    <?php
$referenceArray = array();
$myKeyArr = array();
while($rowKeyword = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlKeyword)){
  $myKeywords = explode(':', $rowKeyword['keywords']);
  $myKeyArr[] = $myKeywords;
}

foreach ($myKeyArr as $value) {
  $kw = array_unique($value);

/*
* checking refernceArray value..
* if vlaue find return empty otherwise it pusy value in array and print desire value
 */

  if (in_array($kw['0'], $referenceArray)){ 
  }
  else{
      array_push($referenceArray,$kw['0']);
      echo $kw['0'] . "<br>";
   }
}

?>
```

I hope it work perfectly.

Comment: That didn't work. Still showing duplicates. Maybe the keywords needs to be pushed into the array one by one, i some way? I'm not sure exploding them, in the db while loop, is the correct way?